# Broadcast large data with Qt sockets

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, udp, qudpsocket

I'm using QT. I need to broadcast data, so I try to use `QUdpSocket`. But data can be too big(after `writeDatagram` `QUdpSocket::error` returns `DatagramTooLargeError`). So I split data and call `writeDatagram` several times to the parts. But Received socket receive data only once, only first packet. Receive code is

```
connect(&m_socketReceiver, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &LocalNetSharing::onDataRead);

void LocalNetSharing::onDataRead()
{
while (m_socketReceiver.hasPendingDatagrams())
{
    QByteArray datagram;
    datagram.resize(m_socketReceiver.pendingDatagramSize());

    m_socketReceiver.readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
    //process data
}
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee UDP packets will be delivered. There is also latency issues you need to consider. If the datagram is not delivered immediately your `while` loop may not see it in time and bail out.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I  understand that while loop can not see it, but in that case another readyRead signal should be emitted, I believe

Answer (score 1):

From the Qt documentation about `QUdpSocket` Class :

> Note: An incoming datagram should be read when you receive the
>   readyRead() signal, otherwise this signal will not be emitted for the
>   next datagram.

So it seems that you are not reading the entire datagram in each call of `onDataRead`.

You don't specify host and port in `readDatagram`. I am not sure if it is the reason but the correct form is :

```
while (m_socketReceiver.hasPendingDatagrams())
{
     QByteArray datagram;
     datagram.resize(m_socketReceiver.pendingDatagramSize());
     m_socketReceiver.readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), host, &port);
     //process data
}
```

Comment: It's same with port and host passed